# Call function from one BFF to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side

I am new to node and epxress.

Say I have a two BFFs - BFF A and BFF B.
In Bff B I have a function someFunc

```
export const someFunc = async (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> => {
    const id = req?.query?.Id;
    await renewSession(String(id));
    const { ID_TOKEN_KEY } = buildCacheKeys(String(id));
    const token = await CacheService.get(ID_TOKEN_KEY);
    const logged = !!token;
    res.send({ logged, token });
};
```

I want to call this function someFunc in BFF B from BFF A. How do I achieve this?

Both the bffs are using node js and express and both are connected to each other via ngrok tunneling.

Comment: What does BFF stand for (apart from best-friend forever)?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a backend for the frontend but not sure. If you want a call function from one service by another service you can use gRPC but probably REST endpoint will be the better (simpler) solution?

Comment: BFF is Backend for frontend @evolutionxbox

Comment: I don't think you can just straight up call a function from one node instance in another.